# Specifying a lambda function as default argument

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

How do I assign a lambda as default argument? I would like to do this:

```
int foo(int i, std::function<int(int)> f = [](int x) -> int { return x / 2; })
{
    return f(i);
}
```

but my compiler (g++ 4.6 on Mac OS X) complains:

```
error: local variable 'x' may not appear in this context
```

**EDIT**:
Indeed, this was a compiler bug. The above code works fine with a recent version of gcc (4.7-20120225).

Comment: I wonder if it's an issue with gcc or if the standard forbids it.

Comment: Just to add, MSVC (2010) spews the same warning: `error C2587: 'x' : illegal use of local variable as default parameter` - `see declaration of 'x'`. It seems to because of the parameter, if I remove it from the lambda, `std::function` and function call, it compiles perfectly fine.

Comment: @Xeo: I wonder how VC2011 reacts to this syntax, since it has improved lambda support.

Comment: Works now (Feb 24, 2017) with clang-800.0.42.1 via `clang++ -c -std=c++11`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use overloading:

```
int foo(int i)
{
    return foo(i, [](int x) -> int { return x / 2; });
}

int foo(int i, std::function<int(int)> f)
{
    return f(i);
}
```

Comment: Like Matthieu, I am not sure whether the issue is a bug in gcc or intentional. Your workaround seems the best solution at the moment.

Comment: Ahh, java-style default parameters. A sight for sore eyes (not!)

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a bug in gcc; the standard permits lambda expressions in default parameters as long as nothing is captured.

The following seems to be everything the FDIS says about lambdas in default parameters, so any use other than what is forbidden here ought to be permitted by default.

> ***C++11 FDIS 5.1.2/13***
>
> A lambda-expression appearing in a
>   default argument shall not implicitly
>   or explicitly capture any entity.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> void f2() {
>     int i = 1;
>     void g1(int = ([i]{ return i; })());       // ill-formed
>     void g2(int = ([i]{ return 0; })());       // ill-formed
>     void g3(int = ([=]{ return i; })());       // ill-formed
>     void g4(int = ([=]{ return 0; })());       // OK
>     void g5(int = ([]{ return sizeof i; })()); // OK
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: Note that, in all those examples there is no parameter, and that's what the compiler chokes on (even in VS2010).

Comment: @Xeo - Yeah, but nowhere in the standard does it explicitly forbid parameters in lambdas used as default argument (that would be a very silly restriction indeed), so both compilers are simply buggy.

Comment: These examples are slightly different -- these are *executing* a lambda *to obtain* a function argument's default value; does this really imply that the lambda itself can be a default value?

Comment: @ildjarn - The example itself is non-normative, but the grammar clearly permits a default argument that is a lambda expression, and AFAICS there exists no normative text that specifically makes an exception to what the grammar says.