# How to create an array constructor for my class?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I would like to create a constructor, which is similar to the `int` array constructor: `int foo[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };`

But I would like to use it like this:

```
MyClass<3> foo = { 4, 5, 6 };
```

There is a private `n` size array in my class:

```
template<const int n=2>
class MyClass {

    public:

        // code...

    private:

        int numbers[n];

        // code...

};
```

Comment: Try googling `c++11 initializer list`

Comment: The type `int[3]` is not a class type, so it doesn't have a constructor. It can be *initialized*, but not via a constructor call.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need a constructor that accepts a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) argument:

```
MyClass(std::initializer_list<int> l)
{
    ...if l.size() != n throw / exit / assert etc....
    std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), &numbers[0]);
}
```

[TemplateRex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819272/templaterex) commented...

> You might want to warn that [such constructors are very greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19847960/819272) and can easily lead to unwanted behavior. E.g. `MyClass` should not have constructors taking a pair of `int`s.

...and was nervous a hyperactive moderator might delete it, so here it is in relative safety. :-)

Comment: You might want to warn that [such constructors are very greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19847960/819272) and can easily lead to unwanted behavior. E.g. `MyClass` should not have constructors taking a pair of `int`s e.g.

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717823/can-using-a-lambda-in-header-files-violate-the-odr#comment57382669_34721371) for greedy moderation.